# Rails: Building a Multi-Model Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that save a question and five answers in the database but I don't know how I can save the answers, this is my form:

```
<%= form_for([:admin, @question]) do |f| %>

...

<%= f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.label :answer, "Risposta", :class => "v-align" %>
    <%= builder.text_field :answer, :rows => 2 %>

    <%= builder.label :correct, "Corretta", :class => "v-align" %>
    <%= builder.check_box :correct %>
<% end %>

...

<% end %>
```

My models:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :answers
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
    attr_accessible :answers_attributes, :quiz_id, :question, :sort_order, :point_value, :number_correct, :explanation
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question
    attr_accessible :question_id, :answer, :correct, :sort_order
end
```

And my "Question" controller:

```
def new
    @question = Question.new
    5.times { @question.answers.build }

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # new.html.erb
        format.json { render :json => @question }
    end
end

def create
    @question = Question.new(params[:question])

    respond_to do |format|
        if @question.save
            format.html { redirect_to admin_question_path(@question), :notice => 'Test was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :json => @question, :status => :created, :location => @question }
        else
            format.html { render :action => "new" }
            format.json { render :json => @question.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end  
end
```

What I should do to save question and answer in the database?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only miss `accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers`in the `Question` model.

[See doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

EDIT:

You should add `answers_attributes` to your `attr_accessible` list

Comment: Ops, I have it in the model but I miss it in this question... sorry!!

Comment: a mere `@question.save` should be ok. But proceed as done in scaffolding to handle errors. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-new-posts

Comment: No, nothing... with @question.save I can save the question but I can't save the answers...

Comment: Did you set some attr_accessible?

Comment: yes but I still can't save answers... I think that I have to write something in the create action of question controller...

Comment: I updated my code but still nothing... :( 
Show my updated question to see how is my code now...

Comment: what is `a[:content]` supposed to be? if it's always blank, everything would be rejected. Try commenting it

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at two RailsCasts:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 and http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

They might help you a lot!

The man behind those casts, Ryan Bates, created a great gem to handle nested forms!